# What is the meaning of bit allocation point and size in Elecard Stream Eye while analyzing h264?

Tags: h.264

I want to use Elecard Stream Eye to analyze H264 frame size. However, it shows a metric named "bit allocation". What is it? What is the difference between "bit allocation" and "size" marked in the picture?

And in the left part, the "bit allocation" shows a number of "9 609 680 [3511]", what is the meaning of "[3511]"?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Size is the size in bits of the current frame on its own.

Bit allocation is the measure of how many bits were spent by the encoder in the last second of content ([source](https://www.elecard.com/question/what-is-bit-allocation)).